# Recalculate each point in dataframe with lapply/sapply

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I write my own function named batcheffect to recalculate all values in a dataframe. 
The function only needs the dataframe as import. First, the mean is calculated in the function and then for each point in the dataframe the calculation is made and create a new dataframe.

```
batcheffect <- function (experiment){    
   corr<-list()    
   matrixexp<-as.matrix(experiment)    
   expmean <-mean(matrixexp)

   for (i in 1:length(matrixexp)){    
      correction <- (matrixexp[i]-overallmean - expmean)+overallmean    
      corr[[i]]<- matrix(correction)
   }
   return(unlist(corr)) 
}
```

For a large dataframe the loop inside a function is slow. So i want to use a sapply or lapply function to speed up the process. Has anyone a suggestion?

Thanks

UPDATE:
For example I have a dataframe like this
    df<- data.frame(A=1:10,B=10:1,C=11:20,C1=21:30,B1=31:40,A2=41:50)

To calculate the mean for all values in the dataframe. The dataframe is converted to a matrix
    df1<-as.matrix(df)
    overallmean<-mean(df1)

The first goal of the data is to make subsets by colnames. You generate three groups, group with A's, group with B's and group with C's. the subsets are defined by the following code:

```
"selectexperiments" <- function (partialname, data) 
{
result <- data[,grep(partialname, colnames(data))]
return(result)
}
A<-selectexperiments('A', df)
B<-selectexperiments('B', df)
C<-selectexperiments('C', df)
```

The three groups are created. For each value in e.g.group A I want to caluclate the following sum:
    (value - overallmean -meanofthegroup) + overallmean.
therefore I create this batcheffect function.

```
"batcheffect" <- function (group)
{
corr<-list()
matrixexp<-as.matrix(group)
expmean <-mean(matrixexp) #mean of the group
for (i in 1:length(matrixexp)){ 
correction <- (matrixexp[i]-overallmean - expmean)+overallmean
corr[[i]]<- matrix(correction)
}
return(unlist(corr))
}

Abatch<-batcheffect(A)
```

The result is OK now, But I will returned the result as a dataframe. And for my own data this function is realy slow so, i thought maby is there a speeding up method like sapply of something.

Comment: could you give an example dataframe, and explain where overallmean comes from?

Comment: @csgillespie : please refrain from editing code in a question. You shouldn't "optimalize" code when editing. This can lead to utter confusion.

Comment: @Joris: Sorry, my mistake. I didn't mean to alter the code, only indent it. I accidentally deleted (as you spotted) the `as.matrix` line. I presume that you don't have a problem with "code formatting"?

Comment: @csgillespie : no problem with formatting, and I only noticed it was gone given the comment of Richie on my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is pretty odd. It can be simplified to :

```
batcheffect <- function (experiment){
    matrixexp<-as.matrix(experiment)
    expmean <-mean(matrixexp)
    c(matrixexp - expmean)
}
```

and will give exactly the same result. Simple calculus shows that

`(matrixexp[i]-overallmean - expmean)+overallmean`

is perfectly equal to

`matrixexp[i]- expmean`

And as R calculations are vectorized a loop is not necessary. It returns a vector (hence the `c()` function).

Using `unlist()`, you can further simplify to:

```
batcheffect2 <- function(experiment){
  x <- unlist(experiment,use.names=F)
  x - mean(x)
}
```

which again returns exactly the same result. Are you sure this is what you had in mind?

---

EDIT :

Given your comments, I add here the test code. I named your original function `old.batcheffect()`. As you see, on a sample dataframe (and after initialization of the mystery `overallmean`) the result of all functions is identical :

```
> Df <- data.frame(A1=1:10,B1=10:1,C1=11:20)
> overallmean <- runif(1)
> X1 <- old.batcheffect(Df)
> X2 <- batcheffect(Df)
> X3 <- batcheffect2(Df)

> all.equal(X1,X2)
[1] TRUE
> all.equal(X2,X3)
[1] TRUE
```

---

EDIT2 :

To get batcheffect returning a dataframe like the original, you just need one line of code :

```
batcheffect <- function(x) x - mean(unlist(x))
```

You can now process the complete original dataframe within one function :

```
summaryBatch <- function(data,groups){
    tmp <- lapply(groups,function(x){
        data[,grep(x,names(data))]
    })
    out <- lapply(tmp,function(x){
        x - mean(unlist(x))

    })
    do.call(cbind,out)
}
```

Then :

```
summaryBatch(df,c("A","B","C"))
```

returns a dataframe with all columns, where for each column the group mean is substracted. As said before, you can add and subsequently remove the overallmean, but that doesn't make a difference at all.

Comment: Yeah that is what I mean but, now you created an list with values. to convert it to a dataframe, the values aren't on the good place. The c(matrixexp - expmean) reads vertically and the unlist() function replace hozitontally. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @Lisann : I get twice exactly the same vector. And if I set an overallmean of eg 20 in my global, I get exactly the same vector with all three functios. So I don't know what you mean, these functions do *exactly* the same. unless your experiment is not a dataframe off course...

Comment: @Lisann : btw, unlist() works vertically as well. Try following code to see : `Df <- data.frame(A=1:10,B=10:1,C=11:20) ;
all.equal(unlist(Df,use.names=F),c(as.matrix(Df)))`

Comment: More oddities: `matrixexp` and `overallmean` are used by the function but not defined there.  That means that your function behaves differently depending upon the state of other environments (e.g., whether or not you defined those variables in your user workspace).  This will invariably lead to buggy code.

Comment: my experiment is not ok! It calulate each value vertically and put it back horizontally. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: Even more oddities: If your `experiment` data frame is convertible to a matrix (are all the columns numeric?), then perhaps you should just define it to be a matrix in the first place, rather than having two variables.  Finally, the name `expmean` is confusing; I thought it meant `exp(mean)` first.  `experiment_mean` is clearer.

Comment: @Lisann : then you'll have to adapt your function and explain what you are doing outside the code you gave. I'll add the test code, so please tell me what you do different.

Comment: @joris I edited the script with an example. maybe It's cleare now?

Comment: @Lisann : I tried it out, and all three functions - again - give the same result. Also your own function returns a simple vector, so I really don't get the problem, sorry.

Comment: But how can Abatch in the example, converted to a dataframe?